# How to do a box around equation

Tags: boxes

I need to do this box [image]. How can I do that?

Comment: I tried but result is box around whole equation, not like in the picture.

Comment: ok, I misunderstood your question. I thought your picture shown your current result, and not what you're expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hackjob to get

[image]

First I print a boxed equation with horizontal space equivalent of the root, then print the root in box with white background on top.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\[
\fboxsep=1pt\relax
\newcommand\MyRoot{{}= \sqrt{\frac{4\pi\delta}{\sigma_1\bigl((X+Y)(X-Y)\bigr)^{\sigma_2}}}}
\ooalign{%
$\displaystyle\boxed{\hat{g} \hphantom{\displaystyle\MyRoot} \approx 999.121}$\cr
\fboxsep=0pt\relax\hspace{0.8em}\colorbox{white}{$\displaystyle\MyRoot$}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

egreg suggests using `\boxed` macro of the `amsmath` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\fboxsep=1pt\relax
\boxed{\hat g} = \sqrt{\frac{4\pi\delta}{\sigma_1\bigl((X+Y)(X-Y)\bigr)^{\sigma_2}}} 
\boxed{{}\approx 999.121}
\]
\end{document}
```

Without any packages, (i.e., with `\fbox`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\fboxsep=1pt\relax
\fbox{$\hat g$} = \sqrt{\frac{4\pi\delta}{\sigma_1\bigl((X+Y)(X-Y)\bigr)^{\sigma_2}}} 
\fbox{${}\approx 999.121$}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**FOLLOW UP**

I did not originally perceive the 3-sided nature of the applied boxes in the OP's figure.  That can be achieved using the current method, with the addition of a `\clipbox` upon the `\fbox`.  It has been macroed as `\boxl{}` and `\boxr{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\newcommand\boxl[1]{\clipbox{0pt 0pt 1.4\fboxrule{} 0pt}{\fbox{$#1{}$}}}
\newcommand\boxr[1]{\clipbox{1.4\fboxrule{} 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\fbox{${}#1$}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\fboxsep=1pt\relax
\boxl{\hat g}
= \sqrt{\frac{4\pi\delta}{\sigma_1\bigl((X+Y)(X-Y)\bigr)^{\sigma_2}}} 
\boxr{\approx 999.121}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Load `amsmath` and use `\boxed`